# How to schedule a real time data pipeline (flume, kafka, spark streaming)?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka, pipeline, flume-ng, orchestration

I have a batch processing data pipeline on a Cloudera Hadoop platform - files being processed via Flume and Spark into Hive. The orchestration is done via Oozie workflows.

I'm now building a near-real-time data pipeline using Flume, Kafka, Spark Streaming and finally into HBase. There are 2 scenarios in terms of orchestration :

1. Keep the pipeline on 24/7 - What should be the orchestration (scheduling) mechanism? Oozie?
2. Operate the pipeline between 8 am and 8 pm - What should be the orchestration (scheduling) mechanism? Oozie?

Please describe your experiences from real-life production implementations.

Comment: Why do you need a schedule? Flume and Kafka is always running. Spark Streaming would always be writing to Hbase too, for example

Answer (score 1):

**Scenario 1 - 24/7 pipeline**

The processes in pipeline must be running always. Scheduler is not a right choice for it, as processes are not being scheduled here but processes should be monitored and restarted if these die. The flume agents and spark streaming driver running as a client should be executed through systemd. Systemd will take care of restarting flume agent or spark streaming driver dies. If spark streaming driver is running in cluster mode, run it with supervisor flag on and you will not need systemd unit for it.

**Scenario 2 - 8 AM to 8 PM**

If you have systemd unit for both flume agent and spark streaming driver in client mode, two scripts could be written, one for starting these processes and other for stopping these processes. You can schedule start processes script at 8 AM either using oozie or crontab and schedule stop processes script at 8 PM.